# Variables evaluated to False in a tuple

Tags: python, boolean, tuples, transition

Why are the `inSetStates`, `inInputAlph` and `isCorrectDirection` variables evaluated to `False` in the following code:

```
class POC(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.__set_states = (1,2,3,4,5)
    self.__input_alph = ('a','b')
    self.__directions = ('i','d')

  def enterTransition(self):
    while True:
      print "enter transition tuple format:"
      trans = raw_input(" Example (1,'a',2,'b','d') : ")
      inSetStates = (trans[0] in self.__set_states) and (trans[2] in self.__set_states)
      inInputAlph = (trans[1]in self.__input_alph) and (trans[3] in self.__input_alph)
      isCorrectDirection = (trans[4].lower() in self.__directions) or (trans[4].lower() in self.__directions)
      if (inSetStates and inInputAlph and isCorrectDirection):
        return trans
        break
      else:
        print "ERROR: Something is wrong"

poc = POC()
poc.enterTransition()
```

The debugger shows me that the value of the `three` is `False` with the tuple `(1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'd')`, and:

```
inInputAlph = False
inSetStates = False
isCorrectDirection = False
self = <__main__.POC object at 0x1860690>
trans = "(1,\'a\',2,\'b\',\'i\')"
```

*Also, I've no idea what these backslashes are.*

Answer (score 7):

`trans` is a string, not a tuple. Strings are indexable too, so `trans[1]` is then the *string* `'1`' (the character at position 1).

You'd need to convert the input to a tuple first. An easy method to do that would be to use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
 >>> import ast
 >>> ast.literal_eval("(1,\'a\',2,\'b\',\'i\')")
 (1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'i')
```

The `.literal_eval()` function interprets it's input as a python literal, and will try and return you a python value that matches that input.